# Crop and cut video while keeping encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, images, editing

I have a whole bunch of large video files, which I would like to both crop and cut:

- Crop: I don't need the entirety of the dimensions of each video; instead, I would like to specify a smaller rectangle within those dimensions that should become the new video dimensions. I don't want to scale the video down: But cut out everything that is not in the rectangle, thus saving space by getting rid of useless pixels.
- Cut: Given that filesize is important to me, I want to be able to cut out parts of the video that have no relevancy. This both means trimming the beginning and the end to a certain point, but also cutting out parts of various sizes in between, and sticking the remaining parts back together into one video.

By now I've tried plenty of programs/tools to try and achieve my goal, but unless I misused them, none managed to easily do what I wanted without either giving a LARGER filesize (Even though the remaining dimensions were smaller, and the video was shorter), incredible amount of quality loss, or taking literal days to achieve the result, on an input file of only about 100MB.

What would be the easiest way to get access to crop and cut functions, without losing a ton of quality and encode it into a well-compressed file format? I know this isn't how it works, but essentially I just want to cut out unneeded information, but keep the remaining information the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Cutting is an operation that can be typically be performed losslessly without the need to reencode so you gain storage space. As for cropping I don't know. You either don'
t crop or change the encoding settings in a way that you pay quality but gain storage space or at least do not loose space after reencoding.

Comment: What is the video codec of the video files?

Comment: @r2d3 I mean, from a purely theoretical point of view, cropping should be able to be done without paying quality and while gaining storage as well. You will need to re-encode, sure, but in the end the amount of information encoded will always be far smaller

Comment: @Rotem I have a *lot* of different files, but I believe the majority is H264.

Comment: It is **not** possible to crop H.264 encoded video without re-encoding (since re-encoding is lossy operation the quality is going to be lower). In case you consider minor quality loss, it may be possible (depends on the resolution of the cropped ROI). Reencode using `-vcodec libx264` and `-crf 17`, and `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, and check if you see quality degradation, and if the file size is smaller. (Note: using `libx265` you can get about 30% smaller size with the same quality as H.264, but it takes longer to re-encode).

Comment: If the cropping is for presentation purposes only (and not file size), then H.264 can be cropped without re-encoding by setting metadata in the SPS. See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmetadata